# place same file type in a folder

Tags: c#, directory, imagemagick, magick.net

I am using Magick.NET and C# Console. The code below finds all the `.eps` file and then converting it to `.jpg`.

```
foreach (string fileName in Directory.GetFiles("C:/Users/Adrian/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/ImageMagickTest/ImageMagickTest/bin/Debug/eps","*.eps"))
                {
                    using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\n\nNow Converting. Please Wait...\n\n");
                        image.Read(fileName, settings);
                        image.Write(fileName.Substring(0,fileName.Length - 3) + ".jpg");
                        i++;
                        Console.WriteLine("Conversion Success.\n\n");
                        Console.WriteLine("Files Converted: " + i); 
                    }
                }
```

Now, what I want is to separate .eps from .jpg.
for example:

folder `/eps/` contents:

- image1.eps
- image2.eps

after executing the loop. the folder `/eps/` contents will be:

- image1.eps
- image2.eps
- image1.jpg
- image2.jpg

How will i place the .jpg in a different folder?

Comment: I'll check your answers maybe tommorow or friday. gtg.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want a jpg folder? Add this to create the folder before your foreach loop.

```
       if (!Directory.Exists("C:/Users/Adrian/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/ImageMagickTest/ImageMagickTest/bin/Debug/jpg"))
       {
           Directory.CreateDirectory("C:/Users/Adrian/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/ImageMagickTest/ImageMagickTest/bin/Debug/jpg");
       }
```

I'm also assuming `image.Write` will actually create the file, if so then you can change the following line

```
image.Write(fileName.Substring(0,fileName.Length - 3) + ".jpg");
```

To be something like this

```
image.Write(fileName.Substring(0,fileName.Length - 7) + "jpg/.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

E.g.

```
// Set the source folder to whatever.
var sourceFolderPath = "...";

// Create the destination folder path by removing the leaf folder name and replacing it with another.
var destinationFolderPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(sourceFolderPath), "jpg");

foreach (var sourceFilePath in Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolderPath, "*.eps"))
{
    // Build the destination file path from the desitination folder path, file name and a new extension.
    var destinationFilePath = Path.ChangeExtension(Path.Combine(destinationFolderPath, Path.GetFileName(sourceFilePath)), ".jpg");

    // Use destinationFilePath here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think This code will give you exactly what you want

```
foreach (string fileName in Directory.GetFiles("Folder","*.eps"))
            {
                using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\nNow Converting. Please Wait...\n\n");
                    image.Read(fileName, settings);
                    string[] split = filename.Split('\\');
                    string clear_file_name = split[split.Length-1];
                    string split_file_name= clear_file_name.split('.');
                    string filename_without_extention = split_file_name[0];  
                    if(!Directory.Exists(folder+"\\jpeg"))
                        Directory.Create(folder+"\\jpeg");
                    image.Write(fileName.Substring(0,folder+"\\jpeg\\"+file_name_without_extention+".jpg");
                    i++;
                    Console.WriteLine("Conversion Success.\n\n");
                    Console.WriteLine("Files Converted: " + i); 
                }
            }
```